# Turn an onClick function within a RecyclerView to a if statement

Tags: java, android

I have a RecyclerView that has 3 Images, red, yellow and green. What I want to do, is if the user clicks on the image, it should cycle through the images:

This is the onBindViewHolder:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position){

        PlayerDetails thePlayer = playerDataSet.get(position);
            holder.playerView.setText(thePlayer.name+ " " + thePlayer.number);
            holder.greenView.setVisibility(ManualPlayingChange.isToMight(holder.greenView));
            holder.redView.setVisibility(ManualPlayingChange.mightToNot(holder.redView));
          //  holder.playingViews[1].setVisibility((ManualPlayingChange.isToMight(holder.playingViews)));
            //holder.playerView.setText(i.number);
        }
```

Which calls:

```
public static int isToMight(ImageView a) {

        //TODO Create a onClick tht will cycle through all 3 images one by one
        a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View a) {
                a.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });
        return 0; //I don't know why I have this here, but I need it to work?
    }


    public static int mightToNot(ImageView b){

       b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View b) {
               b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           }
       });
    return 0 ;
}
```

How can I create an If statement, to say If clicked then cycle to the next image?

Comment: add **`onclicklistener`** to the ViewHolder view. and inside `onclick()` do your action

Comment: Thanks @JyotiJK will give that a go

Comment: you can make two types of image one is circle and other is without circle when user click then only change images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an onClick example in my project file with using model. You can also use linearLayout to listen. [Check out this](https://github.com/keremoflu/Android-Tutorials/blob/master/Elements%20of%20Android%20Studio/RecyclerView%20with%20Custom%20Adapter/Adapter/MyAdapter.java)

Comment: Thanks for your example!

Comment: Hi, do you know how to pass through more than one View?

Comment: Do you mean this? https://github.com/keremoflu/Android-Tutorials/tree/master/Elements%20of%20Android%20Studio/RecyclerView%20With%20Different%20Custom%20Layouts